# What does the pressure value mean, and what is the scale?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

I can see a "pressure" value on cities which seems to indicate how powerful is the conversion to a religion in a city. But how can I translate that value to some meaning? What does "+4 pressure" imply? What's the difference between +4 and +20? Can I tell how long it will be until a religion converts a citizens by looking at the pressure value?

Comment: How much pressure the civs are being put under to convert? so the higher the better. Unless you already ment that, but want stats on how fast it occurs.

Comment: [This discussion](http://forums.2kgames.com/showthread.php?124224-How-does-Religious-Pressure-work) could help.

Answer (score 8):

It definitely appears to be a flat scale, 12 pressure converts twice as fast as 6 pressure. I had one city with 12 christian pressure and 6 Buddhist, and it was 2/3 christian and 1/3 Buddhist after a while. Each successive citizen takes more points of pressure to convert