# How does religious pressure work in Civilization V?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I convert a city to my religion?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/74385/how-do-i-convert-a-city-to-my-religion)

How is the religious pressure at a city calculated? I was fighting with another religion for religious control of a city state and was trying to make my religious pressure higher.

Comment: Have you seen [this excellent answer by Lawton](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/74444/122)? I think it fully answers your question...

Comment: Why thank you. I agree on the excellency of my answer, and would direct you to it. :)