# What formula does religious pressure adhere to in Civ 5?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the pressure value mean, and what is the scale?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/74337/what-does-the-pressure-value-mean-and-what-is-the-scale)

My religion of Atheism is exerting 8 "pressure" on a city's population, and a contending religion of Christianity is exerting 16 "pressure" on this same population. Obviously this would mean that a greater number of my citizens in this city would tend toward the heathen religion of Christianity over a period of time. My question is how "pressure" can be **mathematically** expressed as **a conversion of population over time**? How does pressure correlate with the number of citizens that will be converted over time? Also, how do other nearby cities exerting religious pressure factor in determining pressure and does the distance among cities have any bearing on the degree of pressure?

Comment: Yes, but I am taking into account the variables of pressure, time and distance not just "how does pressure convert citizens over time". I am looking for a formula here so please bear with me.

Comment: You're probably looking for this question then: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/74385/how-do-i-convert-a-city-to-my-religion

Comment: Please don't edit out the auto-generated links.

Comment: Don't be fools. I have edited this question appropriately and you dismiss it for being a duplicate. I am looking for an answer in the form of "x pressure from y cities with z populations will convert p citizens in q turns". The reply " A city with 12 pressure from christianity and 6 from shinto will gradually become 2/3 christian and 1/3 shinto" is vague and does not satisfy what I am asking. Quantify "gradually" for me. What more do I need to do re-open this question?

Comment: If you're looking for more information, request it on the duplicate; you have enough rep to comment.  Alternatively, you can add a bounty to it, and that may give it more attention to get the answer you're looking for.  If these solutions are not desirable, and you feel like question isn't a duplicate, though, you're free to state your case on [meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/).